# Mysql - Check if VARCHAR column has a missing value on its incrementation

Tags: mysql, sql, auto-increment, varchar

I'm trying to find out if my values inserted are auto-incrementing correctly or if for any reason one has failed to be inserted, deleted or gone "missing". I've tried several answers from Stackoverflow but they were mainly pointing out autoincrementable int values so they did not help since mine is a VARCHAR value that follows the following sequence:

```
AA000001
AA000002
...
AA000100
...
AA213978
```

and so on...

Thanks for your time.

Comment: is a fixed pattern AAxxxxxx?

Comment: might even be `etc000001` ...

Comment: or can it be 'AAAxxxxx'? Because if only 2 you can use `substring` or `left` or `right` to cut the `varchar`

Comment: @Drew, no, the etc was added to explain that it goes beyond AA213978, sorry for the confusion, lemme fix it.

Comment: my bad attempt at humor

Comment: @JoeTaras Yes it is a fixed pattern.

Comment: so you need to tell the folks what you want as Expected Results for any sanity here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare SQL Vars in Query and calculate the difference in each iteration, as shown in the example below:

Schema

```
create table MyTable
(   ai int auto_increment primary key,
    id varchar(100) not null
);
insert MyTable (id) values
('AA000001'),
('AA000002'),
('AA000005'),
('AA000008'),
('AA000009'),
('AA000010');
```

Query

```
select id 
FROM 
( 
    select 
      t.id, 
      SUBSTRING(t.id,3) as s, 
      CAST(SUBSTRING(t.id,3) AS UNSIGNED) - @lastId as diff, 
      if( @lastId = 0, 0, CAST(SUBSTRING(t.id,3) AS UNSIGNED) - @lastId) as Difference, 
      @lastId := CAST(SUBSTRING(t.id,3) AS UNSIGNED) as dummy 
     from 
      `MyTable` t, 
      ( select @lastId := 0) SQLVars 
     order by 
      t.id 
) d 
WHERE diff>1;
```

This is the inside query (not the final result set of the above)

```
+----------+--------+------+------------+-------+
| id       | s      | diff | Difference | dummy |
+----------+--------+------+------------+-------+
| AA000001 | 000001 |    1 |          0 |     1 |
| AA000002 | 000002 |    1 |          1 |     2 |
| AA000005 | 000005 |    3 |          3 |     5 |
| AA000008 | 000008 |    3 |          3 |     8 |
| AA000009 | 000009 |    1 |          1 |     9 |
| AA000010 | 000010 |    1 |          1 |    10 |
+----------+--------+------+------------+-------+
```

Actual Results of Above Query:

```
+----------+
| id       |
+----------+
| AA000005 |
| AA000008 |
+----------+
```

Here's the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/621ad/6/0).

Comment: table is a reserved word so it needs back-ticks

Comment: There, fixed some typos, not sure that is the result you want

Comment: Forgot to mention that the value inserted is incremental but is not the ID itself, also they can be inserted without consecutively accordign to the ID

Comment: @this.user3272243 It will show the difference between previous row's id and current id. We can check the difference column and if it's more than 1, we can say that an id is skipped.

Answer (score 0):

To simply test if there *are* missing values,

```
select count(*) <> max(right(col, 6))-min(right(col, 6))+1 || count(*) <> count(distinct col)
```